# How to take the slope of the lm regression in the ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, gradient, lm

I have a plot between x and y variable using ggplot and sepcifically the following code:

```
ggplot(data = dataset, aes(x = X, y = log_Y, colour = Year)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE)
```

Is there any way that I can take the slope of the line created by the lm regression?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ggplot is really just meant for visualization. If you need to work with the regression result, you should fit the model outside of ggplot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `broom` package, which simplifies the process of extracting model data. For example:

```
library(broom)
library(dplyr)

fit <- lm(mpg ~ cyl, data = mtcars)
summary(fit)

fit %>%
    tidy() %>%
    filter(term == "cyl") %>%
    pull(estimate)
```